# Calculate concordance and correlation in a text file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file with 4 columns and 300 rows. Every Id occurs twice. Based on if column 4 is a match for both the 2 occurrences of ids (like id 2 and 3) calculate the percentage of matches. In this case 2 ids match perfectly (both the occurrences match) so it will be 2/4 =0.5. also calculate the percentage of single matches. And calculate correlation between column 2 & column 3. I know how to do it in excel but it is too time consuming as i have many files. How can we do it in linux? May be awk or sed.

My file contents as below

```
1 12 12 match
1 13 12 mismatch
2 5 5 match
2 4 4 match
3 17 17 match
3 12 12 match
4 12 13 mismatch
4 12 14 mismatch
```

Desired output

```
Perfect match =0.5, Single match =1/8 =0.1, Correlation = 0.98
```

Comment: How is correlation calculated?

Comment: awk seems very sufficient to me. It can process your file row by row. Calculations are possible. (The script language is somehow similar to C. Arithmetic operators and functions are there as well as branch and loop statements (`if`, `for`, `while`)). You may use variables (need not to be declared) to manage global state. Even functions are available. You will find lots of tutorials and examples by google. Btw. I'm afraid, your question is off-topic.

Comment: Many languages could do this, so please show us your attempt and where you are stuck? I would suggesting solving for each before joining it all together.  Along with question above, I would also ask why 1/8 instead of .125?  Is there a decimal restriction?

Comment: I tried excel, first sort col4 , the conditional matching and highlight duplicate ids, the sort according to highlighted cell, then count  and calculate the percentages and correlation.

Comment: @akang, again, elaborate your *calculate correlation between column 2 & column 3*

Comment: @Inian out of 4 ids 2 match perfectly thus 2/4 =0.5

Comment: Shoudn't _single match_ therefore be 1/4=0.25?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i used the inbuilt function in excel https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CORREL-function-995dcef7-0c0a-4bed-a3fb-239d7b68ca92

Comment: @JamesBrown Right.. it was a mistake in question.

Comment: @JamesBrown https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CORREL-function-995dcef7-0c0a-4bed-a3fb-239d7b68ca92 this is what i used

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 2):

In awk (correlation calculation from https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/correlation.html). Two runs. First run calculates the means of `$2` and `$3`, the second run all the other values:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                 # first run
    v2s+=$2               # var $2 sum
    v3s+=$3               # var $3 sum
    next
}
FNR==1 {                  # for the first record of second run
    v2m=v2s/(NR-1)        # var 2 mean
    v3m=v3s/(NR-1)        # var 3 mean
}
{
    m[$1]+=($4=="match")  # count matches for each pair
    a=$2-v2m              # a as in the link above $2-mean
    b=$3-v3m              # b too as above
    ab+=a*b               # ab
    a2+=a*a               # a squared all summed up
    b2+=b*b               # b squared as well
}
END {
    for(i in m) {
        print i, m[i]
        if(m[i]==2)
            pm+=2         # perfect matches
        if(m[i]==1)
            sm+=2         # single matches
    }
    print "Perfect match= " pm/FNR " Single match= " sm/FNR " Correlation= " ab/sqrt(a2*b2)
}' file file
Perfect match= 0.5 Single match= 0.25 Correlation= 0.979748
```

Comment: OK, I need breakfast first. brb.

Comment: Updated and finished.